# Erro laravel migrate

Tags: laravel

Estou com problema ao rodar o comando `php artisan migrate` no laravel, apareceu um erro monstruoso que não entendo pq ocorreu,  vou mandar o link do github pra vocês darem uma olhada e me dar um feedback, no arquivo eu mostro como está a estrutura das minha migrations e logo embaixo o erro que aparece no terminal quando rodo o comando.
https://github.com/brenoo2018/migration.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Procure o ficheiro **AppServiceProvider.php** e acrescente isto:

Importe o Schema.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

**Na função boot()** deixe assim:

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

**Fonte: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error**

Comment: O problema era aí mesmo, fiz a mudança e funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Coloca um tamanho no campo `$table->string('email` que vai resolver o problema, ele reclama pelo tamanho do campo ser muito grande na criação do indice, exemplo de correção que no meu entender o campo e-mail não precisar ser muito grande com 100 acredito ser um tamanho natural:

```
Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->string('email', 100)->index();
       $table->string('token');
       $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
});
```

<sub>**Observação**: se tiver mais campos com o tipo `string` e com obrigação de ter um `índice` tome as medida preventivas passando o tamanho.</sub>

*Observei também que tem muitos campos com tamanho máximo, isso não é bom, precisa ter um estudo da suas tabelas, campos e chaves, porque eu prefiro ter o controle da situação do que deixar o framework tomar todas as decisões.*

---

Além dessa que na minha experiência é a melhor solução, ou seja, adequar os tamanhos dos campos, com estudos prévios, se estiver usando o `Laravel 5.4` altere duas chaves no arquivo `config/database.php`:

**de:**

```
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

**para:**

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

---

[Outra opção, mas, que talvez não seja muito boa porque algumas hospedagem não deixam mudar as configurações dos seus serviços é ativar a opção](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#indexes) `innodb_large_prefix` [para o seu banco de dados, verificando essa opção no banco de dados](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#indexes) `MySQL` *ou* `MariaDB`.

---

[Por fim se quiser colocar nas suas `migrations` um tamanho padrão para `string`, abra o arquivo](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes) `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` [e coloque o comando](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes) `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` [com o tamanho](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes) `191`, *exemplo*:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{   
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
    public function register()
    {   
    }
}
```

*Isso são 4 formas de resolver seu problema, mas, eu prefiro a primeira, porque me dá e garante confiabilidade naquilo que eu estou planejando para meu repositório de informações.*

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Database: Migrations - Index](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#indexes)
- [Laravel 5.4 migration: Specified key was too long error solution](https://geektnt.com/2017/01)
- [Laravel 5.4 failing on php artisan migrate after php artisan make:auth](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-failing-on-php-artisan-migrate-after-php-artisan-makeauth)

Comment: obrigado pela observação Virgilio.

Comment: Complicado levar voto negativo, acredito que sem razão torna sempre um voto inválido.